# Nifi add attribute from DB

Tags: apache-nifi

I am currently getting files from FTP in Nifi, but I have to check some conditions before I fetch the file. The scenario goes some thing like this.

List FTP -> Check Condition -> Fetch FTP

In the Check Condition part, I have fetch some values from DB and compare with the file name. So can I use update attribute to fetch some records from DB and make it like this?

List FTP -> Update Attribute (from DB) -> Route on Attribute -> Fetch FTP

Comment: Could you please **elaborate** regards to what are you need to Fetch values from DB please?

is it based on Filename we need to pull records from DB ?

Comment: The filename contains timestamp and we need to pic the files which contains timestamp higher than the last fetched file. The timestamp from the last fetched file is stored in DB. Hence I need the fetch the last timestamp from DB and check if the filename contains higher timestamp than that, if yes then fetch the file else don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your flow looks something like below

***Flow:***

```
1.ListFTP //to list the files
2.ExecuteSQL //to execute query in db(sample query:select max(timestamp) db_time from table)
3.ConvertAvroToJson //convert the result of executesql to json format
4.EvaluateJsonPath //keep destination as FlowfileAttribute and add new property as db_time as $.db_time
5.ROuteOnAttribute //perform check filename timestamp vs extracted timestamp by using nifi expresson language
6.FetchFile //if condition is true then fetch the file
```

[image]

***RouteOnAttribute Configs:***

I have assumed filename is something like **fn_2017-08-2012:09:10** and executesql has returned **2017-08-2012:08:10**

**Expression:**

```
${filename:substringAfter('_'):toDate("yyyy-MM-ddHH:mm:ss"):toNumber()
:gt(${db_time:toDate("yyyy-MM-ddHH:mm:ss"):toNumber()})}
```

By using above expression we are having `filename value same as ListFTP` filename and `db_time` attribute is added by using `EvaluateJsonPath` processor and we are changing the time stamp to number then comparing.

Refer to [this](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html#dates) link for more details regards to NiFi expression language.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

So if I understand your use case correctly, it is like you are using the external DB only for tracking purpose. So I guess only the latest processed timestamp is enough. In that case, I would suggest you to use `DistributedCache` processors and ControllerServices offered by NiFi instead of relying on an external DB.

With this method, your flow would be like:

`ListFile --> FetchDistributedMapCache --(success)--> RouteOnAttribute -> FetchFile`

**Configure `FetchDistributedMapCache`**

- Cache Entry Identifier - This is the key for your Cache. Set it to something like `lastProcessedTime`
- Put Cache Value In Attribute - Whatever name you give here will be added as a FlowFile attribute with its value being the Cache value. Provide a name, like `latestTimestamp` or `lastProcessedTime`

**Configure `RouteOnAttribute`**

Create a new dynamic relationship by clicking the **(+)** button in the `Properties` tab. Give it a name, like `success` or `matches`. Let's assume, your filenames are of the format `somefile_1534824139` i.e. it has a name and an `_` and the epoch timestamp appended.

In such case, you can leverage `NiFi Expression Language` and make use of the functions it offer. So for the new dynamic relation, you can have an expression like:

- success - `${filename:substringAfter('_'):gt(${lastProcessedTimestamp})}`

This is with the assumption that, in `FetchDistributedMapCache`, you have configured the property `Put Cache Value In Attribute` with the value `lastProcessedTimestamp`.

**Useful Links**

- https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/83118/how-to-put-data-in-putdistributedmapcache.html
- https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html#dates

Comment: This is a better solution but we are not using any Distributed Cache Service as of now. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I understand but I would suggest you to do some test and benchmark both (Cache service vs DB) when you have time. I believe cache service could perform better since we are avoiding the additional overhead involved in the DB operations.

Comment: I accept that cache service would give me better performance. I will try to use this one. Thanks.